# printing randome choices from an array

Tags: c, arrays, function, loops, while-loop

I am working on a function that picks random numbers from a given array and prints them to stdout. These numbers should not repeat and how many numbers are picked is given to the function along with the array. I have a separate test file for the function and a header file as well. Everything compiles fine but when I run the program I get a hang up in the pickNumbers function, nothing is printed and I don't even know if anything is being chosen to begin with.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "head.h"

//program that picks random numbers from the given array
int alreadyPicked(int choices[], int choice);

void pickNumbers(int myArray[],int max)
{
  // delcare/initilize variables
  int i;
  int choices[max];
  int length = sizeof(myArray)/sizeof(myArray[0]);
  // seed rand
  srand(time(NULL));

  // pick a random choice until that given number of choices is reached
  // to make sure non repeat run against alreadyPicked function
  for (i=0; i <= max; i++) {
    do{
      choices[i] = (rand() % max);
    }while (alreadyPicked(choices, choices[i]) == TRUE);
  }

  for (i=0; i <= max; i++) {
     printf("%d", myArray[choices[i]]);
  }
  printf("\n"); 
}

int alreadyPicked(int choices[], int choice)
{
  int i;
  int answer = FALSE;
  for (i=0; i <= (sizeof(choices)/sizeof(choices[0])); i++) {
    if(choices[i] == choice)
      answer = TRUE;
  }
  return answer;
}
```

Comment: What are the arguments for `pickNumbers` when you call this function?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps

```
for (i=0; i <= max; i++) {
```

must be:

```
for (i=0; i < max; i++) {
```

and

```
 for (i=0; i <= (sizeof(choices)/sizeof(choices[0])); i++) {
```

must be:

```
 for (i=0; i < (sizeof(choices)/sizeof(choices[0])); i++) {
```

Comment: No that still gives me the same hang up, I think I maybe missing something when it comes to incrementing the array

Answer (score 0):

In your first "for" loop you have a nested while/do. You increment "i" in your for loop, instead you should increment the variable inside of while/do, otherwise it will hang forever performing such loop because "i" is never incremented.

Replace:

```
for (i=0; i <= max; i++) {
```

by:

```
for (i=0; i < max;) {
```

And also replace:

```
 choices[i] = (rand() % max);
```

By:

```
 choices[i++] = (rand() % max);
```

This way you make sure "i" is being incremented. Also your construction "i<=max" is incorrect since you start from 0, use the way David RF did.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the aforementioned wrong loop tests, the reason for the endless loop is that in `alreadyPicked()` you compare the new choice index with every choice index in `choices[]`, including uninitialized ones and *the new one itself*; thus, `alreadyPicked()` always returns TRUE. I suggest to change to call of `alreadyPicked()` to

```
alreadyPicked(choices, i)
```

and its implementation to

```
int alreadyPicked(int choices[], int choice)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < choice; i++)
    if (choices[i] == choices[choice])
      return TRUE;
  return FALSE;
}
```